# Content on contert_placeholder overlaps on footer

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm using asp.net and the contents of my content_place holder overlaps outside my footer

here is the Footer

[image]

here is my css:

```
.footer {
   background-color: orange;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
text-align:center;
clear:both;
 height: 50px;
}
```

here is the content_place holder css

```
#content_area
{

       width:80%; 
            margin-left:10%; 
            margin-right:10%;
            height:100%;
}
```

How could I make my footer stick in the bottom?or just my make contents stop on overlapping?

Comment: Can you show us the markup of the databound control and the footer, with their container(s)? The inner details of the databound control are probably not necessary.

Comment: databound?sorry I'm kind of a beginner.

Comment: Databound controls are: ListView, FormView, GridView, etc. I was talking about the control that displays the list of products.

Comment: @ConnorsFan updated It.

Comment: @rainalasa are you using `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `<body>` css a `position:relative;`

Add to your css:

```
body {
   position:relative;
   min-height:100%;
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
}
html {
   height:100%;
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;
}
```

To make the `.footer`'s absolute position be relative to the body.

### If that alone didnt help you:

Keep the body css and:

You cannot use the ID of a `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` element for your css design. The reason is that the `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` never gets into the client's browser. This element lives only on the server side, and its purpose is like its name - to be replaced by the content you give it.

To design the contents of your `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` surround it with a `<div>` element and then apply the css styling on the `<div>`.

See example:

```
<div id="content_area_div">
   <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
      <%--Placeholder for the pages--%>
   </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

And your css:

```
#content_area_div
{
   width:80%; 
   margin-left:10%; 
   margin-right:10%;
   height:100%;
}
```

In the client side the only thing that will remain is the surrounding div and the content you will push into the `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`

Hope it helps!

Comment: @rainalasa It didnt move at all? did something change?

Comment: It move a little bit further from the top

Comment: @rainalasa also important: I see you have css selector named `#content_area`. Is content_area the ID of your `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` element? What is the element with this ID?

Comment: Yeah `#content_area` is the **id** of my `asp:ContentPlaceHolder`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111932/discussion-between-idan-b-and-rai-nalasa).

Comment: Yes I already did this one,but I still cannot make the footer stick to the bottom part and make the contents not to overlap.